# In which cases are non-linear learning methods preferred than logistic regression in classification problems?

Tags: machine-learning, regression

We know that neural networks and other learning methods can have better performance relative to logistic regression in some non-linear classification problems. But, it is known too that logistic regression can separate classes with a line that can be curvy if only we add more predictors that are a square, cube, etc of the given predictors (still considered a linear decision boundary).

So my question is, can we theoretically solve any classification problem through logistic regression, or are there limitations that I do not realize that make other non-linear learning methods mandatory to certain classification problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several assumptions that are needed to be satisfied in order for logistic regression to work. From personal experience the two most important assumptions:

1. Features need to be not (or a little) correlated with each other, because if they are correlated then the change of one feature indicates also the change of the other that's a problem when you try to solve the optimization problem
2. May some features not be ordinal

You can also check [here](https://www.statisticssolutions.com/assumptions-of-logistic-regression/) for more information.

Other learning methods such as RandomForest require no such assumptions and may work better for some datasets. But keep in mind the [no free lunch theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_free_lunch_theorem), most of the times you need to get your hands dirty and test several learning models before you decide which works best for your data.

Comment: Thank you very much.